# .htaccess: Redirect all HTTPS to a subdomain, but EXCLUDE one subdomain folder

Tags: htaccess, redirects, https, subdomain

In summary:   (Notice the "https")

- I have `https://www.example.com`
- All need to be re-directed to `https://sub.example.com`
- EXCEPT `https://xyz.example.com/api`

Here is my current `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# EXCLUDE following sub-domains.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^api\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.example\.com$ [NC]

# REDIRECT everyone to
RewriteRule (.*) https://sub.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

BUT ...  the API that is accessed via `https://sub.example.com/api` is BREAKING when the `.htaccess` is implemented! (Notice the `/api` folder.)

Comment: What version of Apache are you on? Is `/api` a filesystem directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an exception *before* your existing rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^api - [L]
```

Comment: Sorry !  Having trouble including blocked code in the comments section, on my MAC !!

Comment: You mean include your code before 'RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on' ?

Comment: Yes. (In one of your earlier comments (not deleted), you seemed to change `xyz` to `api`, but you already reference an `api` subdomain in your existing rules? Is this the same or different? If it is the same then you don't need it in both places.)

Comment: You format `inline code` (in comments) by surrounding the code in _backticks_.

Comment: Tested it ... that did the job !  Thanks ...